# Dimension of the range of a differentiable map

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For a problem I'm working on I have two Banach spaces $X, Y$ and an *injective immersion* $T\colon X \to Y$ (that is, a $C^1$ injective mapping having the property that its (Fréchet) differential $dT (x)$ is injective at any $x \in X$).

I'm mainly interested in the restriction of $T$ to a finite-dimensional subspace $V_n\subset X$. Can I conclude that $T(V_n)\subset Y$ is contained in a subspace of $Y$ having the same dimension as $V_n$?

Thank you.

Comment: I retagged as functional analysis, as the tag wiki indicates that on Math.SE the (functional-analysis) tag covers both linear and nonlinear aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:It is false. Please consider the simplest case $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, you could take $T(x)=\gamma(x)$ to be a smooth curve and so disprove the above claim. Thank you. I'll need to broad the question a little to rule out such counterexamples.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Yes, please have a try.

Comment: Do you think it could be possible to modify your example to obtain an injective immersion
$$ T\colon \mathbb{R}\to \text{some infinite dimensional space}$$
such that its range is not contained in any finite-dimensional subspace? I guess it is, and this would put an end to the question.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I think so.

Comment: I definitely was on a false track and you helped me to notice. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: It is my pleasure.